# How to update the content of a recyclerView in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I made a simple **reminder** app where I am storing the **reminder,date and time** in **SQLite database**.User is allowed to **edit** and **delete** the contents.My **recyclerView** is not updating when user edit the content in a **dialog box**.
    Currently I am reloading the **activity** after each **edit**.Is there is any way to **update** the contents of **recyclerView** on each **edit**???Please help me out.

I will give you my **code**.

```
public class Alarm extends Activity {
    TextView title;
    Button menu, info;
    RecyclerView recycler_alarm;
    SqliteHelper sqliteHelper;
    Alarm_Adapter alarm_adapter;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);
        getAds();
        initialise();
    }
    private void initialise() {

        title = findViewById(R.id.currentMonth);
        menu = findViewById(R.id.settings);
        recycler_alarm=findViewById(R.id.recycler_alarm);
        Typeface karthika = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/Karthika.ttf");
        title.setTypeface(karthika);
        menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Alarm.this, MenuList.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });
        info = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.addEvent);
        info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Alarm.this, Info.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        loadAlarm();


    }

    private void loadAlarm()
    {
        sqliteHelper=new SqliteHelper(Alarm.this);
        final List<Alarm_pojo> alarm_pojoList=sqliteHelper.getdata();
        if(alarm_pojoList!=null&&!alarm_pojoList.isEmpty())
        {
           alarm_adapter=new Alarm_Adapter(Alarm.this,alarm_pojoList);
           linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
           recycler_alarm.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

           alarm_adapter=new Alarm_Adapter(Alarm.this,alarm_pojoList, new Alarm_Adapter.MyAdapterListener() {
               @Override
               public void iconCancelOnClick(View v, final int position) {
                   Log.d("TAG", "iconCancelOnClick at position "+position);
                   final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(Alarm.this);
                   dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alarm_deletion_dialog);
                   try {
                       dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                   }
                   catch(NullPointerException e)
                   {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   Button btn_yes=dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
                   Button btn_no=dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
                   TextView txt_alarm=dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_alarm);
                   String month_alarm=alarm_pojoList.get(position).getMonth_alarm();
                   String date_alarm=alarm_pojoList.get(position).getDate_alarm();
                   String month_name=null;
                   switch(month_alarm)
                   {
                       case "1":
                           month_name="ജനുവരി";
                           break;
                       case "2":
                           month_name="ഫെബ്രുവരി";
                           break;
                       case "3":
                           month_name="മാർച്ച്";
                           break;
                       case "4" :
                           month_name="ഏപ്രിൽ";
                           break;
                       case "5":
                           month_name="മെയ്";
                           break;
                       case "6":
                           month_name="ജൂൺ";
                           break;
                       case "7":
                           month_name="ജൂലൈ";
                           break;
                       case "8" :
                           month_name="ആഗസ്റ്റ്";
                           break;
                       case "9":
                           month_name="സെപ്റ്റംബർ";
                           break;
                       case "10":
                           month_name="ഒക്ടോബർ";
                           break;
                       case "11":
                           month_name="നവംബർ";
                           break;
                       case "12":
                           month_name="ഡിസംബര്";
                           break;

                   }

                   String txt_header=month_name+"\t"+date_alarm+"\t"+"ലെ അലാറം നീക്കം ചെയ്യണോ?";
                   txt_alarm.setText(txt_header);

                   btn_yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View view) {
                           int id=alarm_pojoList.get(position).getId();
                           sqliteHelper.clearAlarmList(id);
                           alarm_pojoList.remove(position);
                           recycler_alarm.setAdapter(alarm_adapter);
                           alarm_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                           dialog.hide();
                       }
                   });
                   btn_no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View view) {
                           dialog.dismiss();
//                           String id=String.valueOf(alarm_pojoList.get(position).getId());
//                           Toast.makeText(Alarm.this,id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   });
                   dialog.show();

               }
               @Override

               public void iconEditOnClick(View v, final int position)
               {
                   sqliteHelper=new SqliteHelper(Alarm.this);
                   final List<Alarm_pojo> alarm_pojoList=sqliteHelper.getdata();
                   Log.d("TAG", "iconEditOnClick at position "+position);
                   int id=alarm_pojoList.get(position).getId();
                   final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(Alarm.this);
                   dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alarm_edit_dialog);
                   try {
                       dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                   }
                   catch(NullPointerException e)
                   {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   Button btn_yes=dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
                   Button btn_no=dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
                   TextView txt_editalarm=dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_editalarm);
                   final TextView txt_month=dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_month);
                   ImageView img_datepicker=dialog.findViewById(R.id.img_datepicker);
                   final TextView txt_hr=dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_hr);
                   final EditText et_reminders=dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_reminders);
                   ImageView img_timepicker=dialog.findViewById(R.id.img_timepicker);
                   String month_alarm=alarm_pojoList.get(position).getMonth_alarm();
                   String date_alarm=alarm_pojoList.get(position).getDate_alarm();
                   String year_alarm=alarm_pojoList.get(position).getYear_alarm();
                   String time_alarm=alarm_pojoList.get(position).getTime_alarm();
                   final String reminder=alarm_pojoList.get(position).getReminder();
                   final String selected_date=date_alarm+"-"+month_alarm+"-"+year_alarm;
                   String month_name=null;
                   switch(month_alarm)
                   {
                       case "1":
                           month_name="ജനുവരി";
                           break;
                       case "2":
                           month_name="ഫെബ്രുവരി";
                           break;
                       case "3":
                           month_name="മാർച്ച്";
                           break;
                       case "4" :
                           month_name="ഏപ്രിൽ";
                           break;
                       case "5":
                           month_name="മെയ്";
                           break;
                       case "6":
                           month_name="ജൂൺ";
                           break;
                       case "7":
                           month_name="ജൂലൈ";
                           break;
                       case "8" :
                           month_name="ആഗസ്റ്റ്";
                           break;
                       case "9":
                           month_name="സെപ്റ്റംബർ";
                           break;
                       case "10":
                           month_name="ഒക്ടോബർ";
                           break;
                       case "11":
                           month_name="നവംബർ";
                           break;
                       case "12":
                           month_name="ഡിസംബര്";
                           break;

                   }
                    String text_header=month_name+"\t"+date_alarm+"\t"+"ലെ അലാറം നിങ്ങൾക്ക് എഡിറ്റുചെയ്യണോ?";
                    txt_editalarm.setText(text_header);
                    txt_month.setText(selected_date);
                    txt_hr.setText(time_alarm);
                    et_reminders.setText(reminder);
                    img_timepicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Calendar mCurrentTime=Calendar.getInstance();
                            int hour=mCurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                            int minute=mCurrentTime.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
                            timePickerDialog=new TimePickerDialog(Alarm.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                                    String convert_hour=convertTime(selectedHour);
                                    String convert_minute=convertTime(selectedMinute);
                                    String time_selected=convert_hour+":"+convert_minute;
                                    final TextView txt_hr=dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_hr);
                                    txt_hr.setText(time_selected);
                                }
                            },hour,minute,true);
                            timePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Time");
                            timePickerDialog.show();
                        }

                    });
                    img_datepicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            //Setting maximum year as current year
                            calendar.set(2019, 11, 31);
                            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                                      int dayOfMonth) {
                                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                                    String myFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"; //In which you need put here
                                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
                                    String selected_date=sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime());
                                    String[] out=selected_date.split("-");
                                    String dateconverted=out[0];
                                    String monthconverted=out[1];
                                    String yearconverted=out[2];
                                    //Formating the date and month selected.
                                    //Removing intial zero appearing in the date and month selection
                                    String actual_date=convertSelection(dateconverted);
                                    String actual_month=convertSelection(monthconverted);
                                    String formatedvalue=actual_date+"-"+actual_month+"-"+yearconverted;
                                    //Setting the actual date on the textview.
                                    txt_month.setText(formatedvalue);
                                }

                            };
                      DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog=new DatePickerDialog(Alarm.this, R.style.MyPickerDialogTheme, date, myCalendar
                                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                           //For avoiding the past days.
                            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 10000);
                            //Restricting date picker to show only current year.
                            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis()+10000);
                            datePickerDialog.show();


                        }
                    });

                    btn_yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            String month_selected = txt_month.getText().toString();
                            String time_selected = txt_hr.getText().toString();
                            String reminders = et_reminders.getText().toString();
                            int id=alarm_pojoList.get(position).getId();

                            if (!month_selected.equals("") && !time_selected.equals("") && !reminders.equals(""))
                            {
                                int result= sqliteHelper.updateAlarm(month_selected,time_selected,reminders,id);
                               if(result>0)
                               {
                                   finish();
                                   startActivity(getIntent());
                                   Toast.makeText(Alarm.this,"Updated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                   dialog.hide();
                               }
                             }
                        else

                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Alarm.this,"Not Updated. Missing input fields!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    });
                    btn_no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            dialog.hide();
                        }
                    });

                   dialog.show();
               }
           });

            recycler_alarm.setAdapter(alarm_adapter);
            alarm_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(Alarm.this,"No Alarms added yet!..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }

    private String convertSelection(String dateconverted) {
        int date=Integer.parseInt(dateconverted);
        if(date>=10)
        {
            return String.valueOf(date);
        }
        else
        {
           return Integer.valueOf(dateconverted).toString();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                finish();
            }

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Alarm.this, CalendarActivity.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    private void getAds() {
        AdView adView = findViewById(R.id.adView1);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }


    private String convertTime(int time_selected) {

        if(time_selected>=10)
        {
            return String.valueOf(time_selected);
        }
        else
        {
            return "0" + String.valueOf(time_selected);
        }
    }




}
```

**strong text**

Comment: Try      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: It is not working

Comment: call that method again

Comment: Not working...Value is not getting updated on recycler View....

Comment: before call that method again clear your List alarm_pojoList

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to set the adapter every time only add the new value in your
alarm_pojoList then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

and also better to use notifyiteminserted() instead of notifyDataSetChanged and pass the size of your list to add the value in the last position of the list or pass 0 if you need to add it in the top of the list

Comment: Value is not getting updated on recyclerView. I am  using two adapters,one for loading the values when activity is launched and another one for handling the click events...When I removed the usages of set adapter in iconEditon click method,just empty activity is popped up.

Comment: use only one when the activity launched and control it by adding and removing in the click events

Comment: also, you need to reduce duplicate code and reduce local variables into methods